# ModuleNotFoundError no module named 'tensorflow' when running script from command line windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

I' trying to run script from command line that classify images.
When I run script from Pycharm terminal it works properly, but when I'm trying to run from command line there is error:

```
File "process.py", line 3, in <module>
   import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

There are several first lines of script:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import json
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: are you using anaconda?
 pip3 show tensorflow what is the output of this command ?

if not using anaconda try this pip install tensorflow==1.2.0 --ignore-installed

Comment: I'm using PyCharm IDE, and when run Python script from PyCharm terminal it works, when try to run script from windows command line it shows me this error.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows_1 check this

Answer (score 0):

The path of the tenserflow module may not be in the paths for searching modules in your python installation. You will have to explicitly add the path of the tenserflow module to your process.py file by

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "<path to tenserflow module>")
import tenserflow as tf
```

The code may be working in pycharm because the path of tenserflow module may be in the module search directories of pycharm.

Comment: I tryied your code with added path to tensorflow module and there is the same erorr.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install tensorflow

OR

pip3 install tensorflow

in terminal/cmd
```

If you are using a virtualenv/venv/anaconda, you will need to activate it